# Magento admin Payment Methods tab Error

Tags: php, magento, admin, payment

My Magento verions is 1.3.2.1

In the admin When i click the System -> Configuration -> Payment Methods it outputs the following error

**Title: Error Form Submission**

**There has been an error processing your request.**

Invalid model for shipping method: flatrateuk

```
Trace:
#0 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Config.php(90): Mage::exception('Mage_Shipping', 'Invalid model f...')
#1 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Config.php(44): Mage_Shipping_Model_Config->_getCarrier('flatrateuk', Array, NULL)
#2 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/AmazonPayments/Block/Adminhtml/Shipping/Methods.php(64): Mage_Shipping_Model_Config->getActiveCarriers(NULL)
#3 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/AmazonPayments/Block/Adminhtml/Shipping/Methods.php(37): Mage_AmazonPayments_Block_Adminhtml_Shipping_Methods->getShippingMethods()
#4 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form/Field.php(89): Mage_AmazonPayments_Block_Adminhtml_Shipping_Methods->_getElementHtml(Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Select))
#5 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Abstract.php(199): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field->render(Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Select))
#6 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Abstract.php(209): Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract->getHtml()
#7 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form/Fieldset.php(51): Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Abstract.php(199): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Fieldset->render(Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset))
#9 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Abstract.php(209): Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract->getHtml()
#10 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/lib/Varien/Data/Form.php(214): Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract->toHtml()
#11 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/lib/Varien/Data/Form.php(226): Varien_Data_Form->toHtml()
#12 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(103): Varien_Data_Form->getHtml()
#13 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/form.phtml(28): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->getFormHtml()
#14 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(144): include('/home/crate/pub...')
#15 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(176): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#16 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(193): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#17 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(646): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#18 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(506): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#19 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(457): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('form', true)
#20 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/system/config/edit.phtml(46): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('form')
#21 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(144): include('/home/crate/pub...')
#22 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(176): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#23 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(193): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#24 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(646): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#25 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#26 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(646): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#27 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(506): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#28 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(457): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#29 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(67): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#30 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(144): include('/home/crate/pub...')
#31 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(176): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#32 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(193): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#33 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(646): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#34 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#35 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(347): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#36 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php(93): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#37 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(376): Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->editAction()
#38 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(248): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#39 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(158): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#40 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/app/Mage.php(459): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#41 /home/crate/public_html/sneakercornerbk.com/index.php(65): Mage::run()
#42 {main}
```

I searched on google but couldn't find an answer. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: Appears you have a 3rd party shipping module that isn't properly installed, have you tried reinstalling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@B00MER is correct. Someone has had a half-baked effort at finishing the flatrateuk module tutorial.

You should be able to work out what is going on from the [original tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/duplicating_flat_rate_shipping_module). Note with interest:

> **How to uninstall the duplicated flat rate module**
>
> *A. Remove the code parts you have added in installation step 3 and 4 from config.xml and system.xml*
> *B. Delete the Flatrateuk.php files from installation step 1 and 2*
> *C. In your database delete all the entries with path like `carriers/flatrateuk%` from the table `core_config_data`*
> *D. Refresh the cache*

Comment: You are great. I re installed it and it works fine now. Thanks